# How to reuse character rig?

Tags: unity-game-engine, maya

I have a 3D character in my game and I have rigged it using Mixamo auto-rigger. As I realised that my character had a lot of polygons for game. I used the rigged fbx in maya and started trimming up the polygons. And when I re-imported the same character the rig does not work and when I go to the rig tab and select configure. the bone seems to be out of the body for some reason.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. And what would be the correct workflow to export a rigged character from maya? I certainly don't wanna pay $79 dollars again to rig the same character through Mixamo.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Consider posting this on [gamedev.se] instead

Answer (score 0):

-change the polycount(retopo)
-import the new mesh (tpose) in your rig scene(highpoly)
-select the highpoly mesh and open "paint skin weights tool"
-select all joints in the list
-select in mode "Select"  / now you have all the skinned joints
-select your new mesh and skin / "smooth bind"
-go to "edit smooth skin" and "Copy Skinn Weights" from the highpoly to the lowpoly mesh